# No OpenGL objects appearing?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

First attempt at using OpenGL to create a Cube.  No cube seems to appear.

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 640
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 480

void KeyRotation(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int action, int mods, int scancode);
void CreateCube(GLfloat centerX, GLfloat centerY, GLfloat centerZ, GLfloat length);
GLfloat rotX = 0.0f;
GLfloat rotY = 0.0f;
int main(void)
{
GLFWwindow* window;
int width, height;
/* Initialize the library */
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
if (!glfwInit())
    return -1;

/* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Rubics Cube", NULL, NULL);
if (!window)
{
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}


glfwSetKeyCallback(window, KeyRotation);
glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS,1);
glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
/* Make the window's context current */
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
glViewport(0.0f, 0.0f, 640, 480);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, 640, 0, 480, 0, 1000);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

GLfloat halfScreenwidth = 640 / 2;
GLfloat halfScreenHeight = 480 / 2;
/* Loop until the user closes the window */
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    /* Render here */
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(halfScreenwidth, halfScreenHeight, -500);
    glRotatef(rotX, 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(rotY, 0, 1, 0);
    glTranslatef(-halfScreenwidth, -halfScreenHeight, -500);

    CreateCube(halfScreenwidth, halfScreenHeight, -500, 200);

    glPopMatrix();
    /* Swap front and back buffers */
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);

    /* Poll for and process events */
    glfwPollEvents();
}

glfwSetKeyCallback(window, KeyRotation);
glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS,1);
glfwTerminate();
return 0;
}

void KeyRotation(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int action, int mods, int scancode)
{
const GLfloat rotspeed = 10;

if (action == GLFW_PRESS || action == GLFW_REPEAT)
{
    switch (key)
    {
    case GLFW_KEY_W:
        rotX -= rotspeed;
    case GLFW_KEY_S:
        rotX += rotspeed;
    case GLFW_KEY_D:
        rotY += rotspeed;
    case GLFW_KEY_A:
        rotY -= rotspeed;
    }
}
}

void CreateCube(GLfloat centerX, GLfloat centerY, GLfloat centerZ, GLfloat length)
{
GLfloat halfsidelength = length / 2;
GLfloat vertices[] =
{
    //front
    centerX - halfsidelength, centerY + halfsidelength, centerZ + halfsidelength, // top left
    centerX + halfsidelength, centerY + halfsidelength, centerZ + halfsidelength, // top right
    centerX + halfsidelength, centerY - halfsidelength, centerZ + halfsidelength, // bottom left
    centerX - halfsidelength, centerY - halfsidelength, centerZ + halfsidelength, // bottom left

    //Back
    centerX - halfsidelength, centerY + halfsidelength, centerZ - halfsidelength, // top left
    centerX + halfsidelength, centerY + halfsidelength, centerZ - halfsidelength, // top right
    centerX + halfsidelength, centerY - halfsidelength, centerZ - halfsidelength, // bottom left
    centerX - halfsidelength, centerY - halfsidelength, centerZ - halfsidelength, // bottom left

    //left
    centerX - halfsidelength, centerY + halfsidelength, centerZ + halfsidelength, // top left
    centerX - halfsidelength, centerY + halfsidelength, centerZ - halfsidelength, // top right
    centerX - halfsidelength, centerY - halfsidelength, centerZ - halfsidelength, // bottom left
    centerX - halfsidelength, centerY - halfsidelength, centerZ + halfsidelength, // bottom left

    //right
    centerX + halfsidelength, centerY + halfsidelength, centerZ + halfsidelength, // top left
    centerX + halfsidelength, centerY + halfsidelength, centerZ - halfsidelength, // top right
    centerX + halfsidelength, centerY - halfsidelength, centerZ - halfsidelength, // bottom left
    centerX + halfsidelength, centerY - halfsidelength, centerZ + halfsidelength, // bottom left

    //top
    centerX - halfsidelength, centerY + halfsidelength, centerZ + halfsidelength, // top left
    centerX - halfsidelength, centerY + halfsidelength, centerZ - halfsidelength, // top right
    centerX + halfsidelength, centerY + halfsidelength, centerZ - halfsidelength, // bottom left
    centerX + halfsidelength, centerY + halfsidelength, centerZ + halfsidelength, // bottom left

    //bottom
    centerX - halfsidelength, centerY - halfsidelength, centerZ + halfsidelength, // top left
    centerX - halfsidelength, centerY - halfsidelength, centerZ - halfsidelength, // top right
    centerX + halfsidelength, centerY - halfsidelength, centerZ - halfsidelength, // bottom left
    centerX + halfsidelength, centerY - halfsidelength, centerZ + halfsidelength // bottom left
};
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 24);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You draw your cube at `(halfScreenwidth, halfScreenHeight, -500)` as global coordinates. It seems you want to rotate the cube around the origin of local coords, so it should be moved to the global center by `(-halfScreenwidth, -halfScreenHeight, 500)` then it can be rotated and translate back to -500 z coord:

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(halfScreenwidth, halfScreenHeight, -500);
glRotatef(rotX, 1, 0, 0);
glRotatef(rotY, 0, 1, 0);
glTranslatef(-halfScreenwidth, -halfScreenHeight, 500);   // FIXED

CreateCube(halfScreenwidth, halfScreenHeight, -500, 200);

glPopMatrix();
```

---

As a side note: how do you want to set the following callback `glfwSetKeyCallback(window, KeyRotation);` when it is after the main loop ?

Comment: That indeed did fix the viewing of the cube, I understand where that makes sense. Now am having trouble with the rotation. I am not sure what you are asking about the callback. After the while loop? or after main()?